# Angular js directive that would allow alpha characters and would include capslock and space

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, input

Below is my angular js directive that would only allow alphabetical characters but the issue is that it disable capslock/space. The goal is not allowing special characters and numbers as input only alphabet but would not disable capslock/space/shift cause in the app the user can input his name in capital letter.Any idea?. I am using directive compared to ng-pattern library.

```
app.directive('validEn', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl, SweetAlert) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                var clean = val.replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');
                console.log("sfdsfd")
                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return clean;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your following regex `var clean = val.replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');` to `var clean = val.replace(/[^a-z|^A-z|^\s]+/g, '');`